# Remove warnings when referencing system stored procedures in SQLProj

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, sqlproj

I use a SQLproj to create a dacpac, and I have stored procedures in it that references systems stored procs.

```
exec @Result1 = sp_addarticle ....
```

When I compile, I have warnings :

```
Warning     SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[MyProc] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sp_addarticle].
```

I changed the call to explicitly define the `sys` schema

```
exec @Resultat1 = [sys].[sp_addarticle] ....
```

but I still have a warning :

```
Warning     SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[PADM_AjoutFonctionPublication] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[sp_addarticle].
```

This is a system procedure, so I don't need to add it to the proj, how can I remove these warnings ?

Comment: tried adding reference to master database?

Comment: how, the warnings are gone ! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors should go away when you add a reference to the master database.